# how to find an earliest date in a string containing dates?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string of dates in of ISO 8601 format. How can I find the earliest date using javascript?

```
var str = '2019-12-31T23:45:00.000-03:00/2020-01-01T10:30:00.000+06:00,2020-01-01T07:15:00.000+07:00/2019-12-31T16:00:00.000-10:00'
```

Before slash is starting time, after slash is finish time, then is comma and it repeats with different dates.

Is this even possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible. please add your try.

Comment: I didn't find anything on google. I searched for how to find earliest date in a string and all that came up was how to find it in an array

Comment: Split the string at the commas into an array. For each of those array elements, split the string at the slash and store the first item (array index 0) from that split in an array. You now have an array of dates and you can use what you found about how to find it (earliest date) in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Start by splitting your string into an array of date strings and converting those to date objects:

```
var str = '2019-12-31T23:45:00.000-03:00/2020-01-01T10:30:00.000+06:00,2020-01-01T07:15:00.000+07:00/2019-12-31T16:00:00.000-10:00'

// Split on slashes and commas to create an array of dates.
var dates = str.split(/\/,/)
  .map(s => new Date(s))
```

That will give you an array of date objects. You can then sort the array by date as converted to epoch milliseconds:

```
// Sort by epoch milliseconds of the date.
dates.sort(function(a, b) { return a.getTime() - b.getTime() })
```

Finally, take the first result, since the list will be sorted by date ascending:

```
var earliest = dates[0]
```

If you need to convert back to ISO format, use `earliest.toISOString()`.

Answer (score 1):

At first you should split your string, then sort your array and pick the first element from the sorted array:

```
let str = '2019-12-31T23:45:00.000-03:00/2020-01-01T10:30:00.000+06:00,2020-01-01T07:15:00.000+07:00/2019-12-31T16:00:00.000-10:00';
let dates = str.split(/[\,/]+/);

let sortedDates = dates.sort((a,b) =>{
    a = a.substring(0, a.lastIndexOf('.'));
    b = b.substring(0, b.lastIndexOf('.'));
    return new Date(a) - new Date(b);
});
console.log(`earliest date is ${sortedDates[0]}`);
```

I've used `substring` function to get date to be parsed by `.parse()` method.

Comment: i want to upvote this as it worked for me but i dont have enough reputation for it :(

Comment: i couldnt when i had under 15 reputation, but got another 3 now, so voted now. thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @fuerteventura You should be able to "accept" this answer too: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

#### Steps:

1. If a *comma* is the separator between the dates, Run a [`split()` on the string.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) i.e `myStringOfDates.split(",")`
2. Step 1. gives you an array of dates. [Run a `map()` on the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). i.e `.map(e=>new Date(e).getTime())`
3. Step 2. gives you an array of unix timestamps of the dates. [Run a `sort()` on the array.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) i.e `.sort((a, b) => a-b)`
4. With the sorted array in Step 3, Get the first item in the array. Thats your earliest date. i.e `myArrayOfSortedTimestamps[0]`
5. From there you're free to change that timestamp in Step 4 to any format  of your liking.
6. Cheers.